# how can I fix xampp mercury server 553 error?

Tags: php, xampp

somebody help me for my php mail functionTQ

```
  <?php
  $to = 'myname@gmail.com';
  $sub = 'this is a test mail';
  $message ='this is a mail :)';
  $from = 'From: postmaster@localhost';
  $m = mail($to,$sub,$message,$from);
  if($m){
  echo'<b>ststus:</b> sent';    
  }else{
  echo'<b>ststus:</b> not sent';
  }
  ?>
```

Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry. in E:\xampp\htdocs\mail\mail.php on line 6
status: not sent

Answer (score 1):

By default, virtual servers like Xampp don't allow you to send mail from localhost because it's not an 'actual' server.

See this answer to make it happen:
[How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: @K55555 Sorry but I'm not sure what you mean